# Bowl of water to humidify

Tags: evaporation

I kept a bowl of water in my room last night, thinking I need to improve the humidity as I had a sore throat. On waking up, I find that the bowl is still filled with water. Why didn't the water evaporate ? Does it mean my room is already too humid ?

Comment: The surface area of the water has a big influence on the rate of evaporation. How deep was the water compared to the size of the surface?

Comment: And if the room is cool the evaporation rate will be low.  This is why humidifiers either heat the water, aerosolize it, or blow air through a wet pad - all will dramatically increase the uptake of water by the air.

Comment: I used a cereal bowl .. the width of the bowl is roughly twice the height of the bowl

Comment: Currently the room temperature is 75 F.

Comment: Or 23.9 C for any non-Americans

Comment: The room's humidity level is 23%.

Comment: I would not expect much of the water to evaporate when kept at room temperature.

Comment: [This article](http://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/evaporation-water-surface-d_690.html) explains how to calculate the rate of evaporation